# CS0012 The type 'AppHostBase' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced

Tags: c#

Есть проект на .NetFramewok 4.6.1, ссылающийся на .NetStandard 2.0 проект в рамках одного решения.

В стандартовском пакете есть класс, унаследованный от класса nuget-пакета ServiceStack. Методы данного класса вызываются в нетфрэймворковском пакете. Вследствие чего возникает

> Ошибка    CS0012  The type 'AppHostBase' is defined in an assembly that is
>   not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'ServiceStack,
>   Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

Версия этого пакета в обоих проектах одна и та же. Клин, ребилд, очистка кэша нугет, чистка bin/obj не помогли